# How to perform frequency analyse and check association same time with data mining algorithems?

Tags: data-mining

There is an data-set which have data of how people change their cloths and footwear day by day.
This dataset have attribute like this

- Date
- Upper_body_cloth_type
- Upper_body_cloth_color
- Lower_body_cloth_type
- Lower_body_cloth_color
- footwear_type
- footwear_color

What are the data mining methods can be use to analyse frequency of using same type and color of cloths by a particular person. and identify connection between each items.

P.S.: I am normally using Rapid miner for data-mining.But mainly i want to know what are the common data mining algorithms i can use for this kind of scenario

Comment: There are many methods that could help you. But Question need to include more information like which tool are you using. There are many tools that could help you in very easy way. You should share more information to get relevant information

Comment: I am normally using Rapid miner for data-mining.But mainly i want to know what are the common data mining algorithms i can use for this kind of scenario

Comment: I think best way to know hidden pattern is by Visualizing Data.You can plot graphs and charts to know. Like if you want to know pattern of foot along with date you should draw chart with date on one axis and footware sale on other axis.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_recognition/